# n-sets and binary numbers - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm going through Combinatorics: A guided tour by David Mazur and in section 1.1, this question is asked:

Let $X=[100]$ and let $Y$ be the set of odd integers. Find $2^{|X\cap Y|}$

So, from what I've seen so far in the first section, there are as many subsets of an $n$-set ($n=100$ here) as there are $n$-digit binary numbers. Which makes sense. So, in order to satisfy $Y$, the last digit of the binary number just needs to be $1$. And there are $2^{99}$ ways to choose/specify the first $99$ digits.

So would $2^{|X\cap Y|}$ just be equal to $2^{99}$ here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with the notation [$100$].  What does it mean?

Comment: @RobertShore $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$

Comment: Do you mean $\left|2^{X\cap Y}\right|$?  $|X\cap Y|=50$, so the answer is $2^{50}$ without further ado.  In any event, what you say isn't correct.

Comment: So how many odd positive integers are there that are less than or equal to $100$?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not sure I understand the formatting you used.

Comment: $|\cdot|$ means cardinality, so $2^{|X\cap Y|}$ is just a number.  $2^{A}$ is one way of writing the set of all subsets of $A$, so if you mean the number of elements of that set, you would write $\left|2^A\right|$  Of course, it's true that $\left|2^A\right|=2^{|A|}$; that's where the notation comes from.